# T-SQL Merge non overlapping times

Tags: sql, merge, overlap

Using SQL 2008 R2 and stuck on this.

I have several sets of timedate ranges and I need to merge the ranges where there is no overlap with the jobs on resource1. In my example data, I want all jobs from ResourceID 1 and those jobs from all other resources where they do not overlap with EXISTING jobs on resource 1 (i.e. imagine I'm trying to select candidates from other resources to fill ResourceID 1 with continuous jobs)

Below is some sample data, my failed attempt and expected results. I managed to excluded everything that should be excluded except job 10

```
-- Need to select all other jobs from all other resources that can be merged into resource 1 where there is no overlap with existing jobs in resource 1 only


CREATE TABLE #Jobs
    (
     resourceID INT
    ,JobNo INT
    ,StartTime SMALLDATETIME
    ,EndTime SMALLDATETIME
    ,ShouldBeOmitted BIT
    )

 INSERT INTO [#Jobs]
        SELECT
            1
           ,1
           ,'2014-08-01 08:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 10:00:00'
           ,0
        UNION
        SELECT
            1
           ,2
           ,'2014-08-01 18:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 20:00:00'
           ,0
        UNION
        SELECT
            2
           ,3
           ,'2014-08-01 07:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 20:00:00' -- should be omitted as ends in middle of job 1
           ,1
        UNION
        SELECT
            2
           ,4
           ,'2014-08-01 09:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 11:00:00' -- should be omitted as starts in middle of job 1
           ,1
        UNION
        SELECT
            2
           ,5
           ,'2014-08-01 10:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 11:00:00' -- OK because it starts exactly at end of job 1
           ,0
        UNION
        SELECT
            2
           ,6
           ,'2014-08-01 12:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 14:00:00' -- OK because no overlap
           ,0
        UNION
        SELECT
            2
           ,7
           ,'2014-08-01 16:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 18:00:00' -- OK because it ends exactly at start of job 2
           ,0
        UNION
        SELECT
            2
           ,8
           ,'2014-08-01 19:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 19:30:00' -- should be omitted as it is inside tme range of job 2
           ,1
        UNION
        SELECT
            2
           ,9
           ,'2014-08-01 20:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 21:00:00'  -- should be OK as it is starts exactly at end of job 2
           ,0
        UNION
        SELECT
            4
           ,10
           ,'2014-08-01 02:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 22:00:00'  -- should be omitted as spans other jobs
           ,1
        UNION
        SELECT
            5
           ,11
           ,'2014-08-01 08:00:00'
           ,'2014-08-01 10:00:00'  -- should be omitted as it matches other job
           ,1


 SELECT
    'Source Data', *
 FROM
    #Jobs 


 SELECT
    'ExpectedResults'
   ,*
 FROM
    [#Jobs] j
 WHERE
    j.[ShouldBeOmitted] = 0

 SELECT
    'MyResults'
   ,[j].[ResourceID]
   ,[j].[JobNo]
   ,[j].[StartTime]
   ,[j].[EndTime]
   ,[j].[ShouldBeOmitted]
 FROM
    #Jobs j
 WHERE
    [ResourceID] = 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
    'MyResults'
   ,[j2].[ResourceID]
   ,[j2].[JobNo]
   ,[j2].[StartTime]
   ,[j2].[EndTime]
   ,[j2].[ShouldBeOmitted]
 FROM
    #Jobs j2
 WHERE
    [ResourceID] != 1
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT
                        1
                     FROM
                        #Jobs
                     WHERE
                        [ResourceID] = 1
                        AND (
                             (
                              -- Starts within existing job
                              j2.[StartTime] >= [StartTime]
                              AND j2.[StartTime] < [EndTime]
                             )
                             OR (
                                 -- Ends withing existing job
                                 j2.[EndTime] > [StartTime]
                                 AND j2.[EndTime] <= [EndTime]
                                )
                            ) )
 ORDER BY
    [j].[resourceID]
   ,j.starttime
```

Would appreciate any help

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Can you edit your question and make it clearer what the input is and what your desired output is?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure that I understand what data you actually need. From your explanation I think that you need all `Jobs` from `Resource 1` and `Jobs` from `Resource 2` that are not ovelapping `Jobs` from `Resource 2`. Here is my solution:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #Jobs AS x1 
WHERE 
    (x1.resourceID = 1) OR 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Jobs AS y INNER JOIN #Jobs z ON 
        (y.resourceID = 2) AND (z.resourceID = 1) AND 
        ((y.StartTime BETWEEN z.StartTime AND z.EndTime) OR (y.EndTime BETWEEN z.StartTime AND z.EndTime) )
        WHERE ((y.resourceID = x1.resourceID) AND (y.JobNo = x1.JobNo)));
```

This SQL returns:

```
resourceID  JobNo   StartTime   EndTime
1   1   2014-08-01 08:00:00 2014-08-01 10:00:00
1   2   2014-08-01 18:00:00 2014-08-01 20:00:00
2   3   2014-08-01 07:00:00 2014-08-09 20:00:00
2   6   2014-08-01 12:00:00 2014-08-01 14:00:00
2   7   2014-08-01 16:00:00 2014-08-09 18:00:00
```

Actually in your example there is a mistake - you point out that the correct element is Job 5 from Resource 2, but it is covered by Job 1 Resource 1.

If I don't understand well please comment.

EDIT: 
This is the query you need (base on difference of the time by 1 minute)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #Jobs AS x1 
WHERE 
    (x1.resourceID = 1) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Jobs AS y 
        INNER JOIN #Jobs AS z ON (y.resourceID = 2) AND (z.resourceID = 1) 
        AND ((y.StartTime BETWEEN z.StartTime AND DATEADD(mi,-1,z.EndTime)) OR (y.EndTime BETWEEN DATEADD(mi,1,z.StartTime) AND z.EndTime))
WHERE (y.resourceID = 2) AND (x1.JobNo = y.JobNo)
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I miskeyed some of the dates. I put 2014-08-09 instead of 2014-08-01. Sorry

Comment: I tried your solution (with corrected data) and couldn't get it to work

Comment: What SQL system do you use, my SQL is set for SQL Server?

Comment: I take your edited data and I receive as correct element only 6. 5 is not correct becase its `start time` 2014-08-01 10:00:00 is equal to `end time` of Job 1 (Resource 1). 7 and 8 time is inside time of Job 2 (Resource 1).

Comment: Take into account that for SQL `start time` 2014-08-01 10:00:00 is equal to `end time` 2014-08-01 10:00:00. If you think that one jobs ends at that time and next starts in exactly the same moment then you have to change end time in the comparison. For example substract 1 second and you will get result that you need in that case.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, Yes an end of 10:00 and start of 10:00 is valid as one job ends immediately the other starts and we only measure to the minute. I'm using SQL 2008 R2. I made a further update to the question and data where the results are correct except exclusion of Job 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61465/discussion-between-bogdan-bogdanov-and-mark1234).